# Python `shelve` read-only mode is not working

Tags: python, python-3.7, shelve

Is [`shelve`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html) read only mode broken? The documentation says the `flag` parameter works as stated in [`dbm.open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dbm.html#dbm.open) so I thought if I opened in read mode I shouldn't  be able to change the shelve object.

The page [here](https://pymotw.com/3/shelve/) also seems to suggest that modifying a shelve object opened as read-only should raise an exception. But I am still able to do the following:

```
Python 3.7.2 (default, Dec 29 2018, 06:19:36) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import shelve
>>> with shelve.open('testdata') as shelf:
...      shelf['two'] = 2222
...      shelf['one'] = 1111
...
```

Next I will open it with `flag='r'` and `writeback=False` just to be sure. But I am able to modify object.

```
>>> with shelve.open('testdata', flag='r', writeback=False) as shelf:
...     for k, v in shelf.items():
...             print('Key: ', k, ' Value: ', v)
...     shelf['two'] = 1111
...     shelf['one'] = 2222
... 
Key:  one  Value:  1111
Key:  two  Value:  2222
```

Just to confirm, opening and printing it out again show that the object indeed did change:

```
>>> with shelve.open('testdata', flag='r', writeback=False) as shelf:
...     for k, v in shelf.items():
...             print('Key: ', k, ' Value: ', v)
... 
Key:  one  Value:  2222
Key:  two  Value:  1111
```

What am I missing? Does this maybe have to do with the choice/implementation of `dbm` on different systems? Running the code on the linked page also does not cause: `ERROR: cannot add item to database` as the page says it should.

—

**UPDATE:** The code in the linked page works as expected, i.e raises and error,  **when** I use an earlier version of Python, namely:

```
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17)
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

as well as on MacOS:

```
Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Apr 26 2018, 08:42:37)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

With 3.7.2 on Ubuntu 18.04, things breakdown. If the filename has extension '.db' it gives:

```
dbm.error: db type is dbm.gnu, but the module is not available
```

and without an extension, the read only mode doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I tracked this down to the use of `ndbm`, `gdbm` or `dumb` in [implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/3.7/Lib/dbm). On a distribution that uses either the `ndbm` or `gdbm` module opening with `flag='r'` works as expected. However, (at least on Ubuntu 18.04 with Python 3.7.2 by Anaconda) if `dumb` is being used, then the behavior is as above in the question and the read only flag does not prevent writes.

For some reason Anaconda was not utilizing the `python3-gdbm` installed on the system. Copying the library from the system files to the anaconda environment as mentioned [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/3.7/Lib/dbm) fixed that problem.

Answer (score -1):

Just in the off chance anyone was/is trying to use Shelve on a shared folder in VirtualBox: it will fail.  Since the gdm module tries to create the database file with permissions x666 and it seems only files can be made with permissions 0x770 in shared folders.  To see if this is your problem, try making your database in /tmp.